# Where does Neo4j store the data?

Tags: neo4j

I am new to Neo4j and doing some test on Ubuntu. I was wondering where does Neo4j store the data. Where do they store the created nodes and relationships?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should help: `dpkg -L neo4j`

config

```
/etc/neo4j/neo4j.properties
/etc/neo4j/neo4j-wrapper.conf
/etc/neo4j/neo4j-http-logging.xml
/etc/neo4j/neo4j-server.properties
```

logs

```
/var/log/neo4j
/var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db/messages.log
```

binaries

```
/usr/bin/neo4j-shell
/usr/bin/neo4j
```

data

```
/var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db
```

store-files

nodes, properties, arrays, strings, relationship-groups, relationships

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup    0 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.nodestore.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup    0 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.propertystore.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup  128 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.propertystore.db.arrays
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup  128 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.propertystore.db.strings
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup   25 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.relationshipgroupstore.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup    0 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.relationshipstore.db



ls -lh /var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db/
total 168K
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup   11 Jul 30 20:41 active_tx_log
drwxr-xr-x 2 neo4j nogroup 4.0K Jul 30 20:41 index
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup    0 Jul 30 20:41 lock
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup  50K Jul 30 20:41 messages.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup   63 Jul 30 20:41 neostore
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup    9 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.id
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup    0 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.labeltokenstore.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup    9 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.labeltokenstore.db.id
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup   38 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.labeltokenstore.db.names
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup    9 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.labeltokenstore.db.names.id
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup    0 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.nodestore.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup    9 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.nodestore.db.id
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup   68 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.nodestore.db.labels
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup    9 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.nodestore.db.labels.id
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup    0 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.propertystore.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup  128 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.propertystore.db.arrays
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup    9 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.id
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup    9 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.propertystore.db.id
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup    0 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.propertystore.db.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup    9 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.propertystore.db.index.id
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup   38 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup    9 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys.id
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup  128 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.propertystore.db.strings
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup    9 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.propertystore.db.strings.id
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup   25 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.relationshipgroupstore.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup    9 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.relationshipgroupstore.db.id
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup    0 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.relationshipstore.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup    9 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.relationshipstore.db.id
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup    0 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.relationshiptypestore.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup    9 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.id
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup   38 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup    9 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names.id
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup   64 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.schemastore.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup    9 Jul 30 20:41 neostore.schemastore.db.id
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup   16 Jul 30 20:41 nioneo_logical.log.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup    4 Jul 30 20:41 nioneo_logical.log.active
drwxr-xr-x 3 neo4j nogroup 4.0K Jul 30 20:41 schema
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup    0 Jul 30 20:41 store_lock
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j nogroup    0 Jul 30 20:41 tm_tx_log.1

dpkg -L neo4j
/.
/etc
/etc/neo4j
/etc/neo4j/neo4j.properties
/etc/neo4j/neo4j-wrapper.conf
/etc/neo4j/neo4j-http-logging.xml
/etc/neo4j/neo4j-server.properties
/etc/neo4j/windows-wrapper-logging.properties
/etc/neo4j/custom-logback.xml
/etc/neo4j/README.txt
/etc/neo4j/logging.properties
/etc/init.d
/etc/init.d/neo4j-service
/var
/var/log
/var/log/neo4j
/var/lib
/var/lib/neo4j
/var/lib/neo4j/data
/var/lib/neo4j/data/README.txt
/var/lib/neo4j/LICENSES.txt
/var/lib/neo4j/CHANGES.txt
/var/lib/neo4j/UPGRADE.txt
/var/lib/neo4j/bin
/var/lib/neo4j/bin/neo4j
/var/lib/neo4j/bin/utils
/var/lib/neo4j/bin/neo4j-installer
/var/lib/neo4j/bin/lib
/var/lib/neo4j/bin/lib/README.txt
/var/lib/neo4j/bin/org.neo4j.server.plist
/var/lib/neo4j/bin/neo4j-shell
/var/lib/neo4j/bin/README.txt
/var/lib/neo4j/README.txt
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/share
/usr/share/neo4j
/usr/share/neo4j/plugins
/usr/share/neo4j/plugins/README.txt
/usr/share/neo4j/system
/usr/share/neo4j/system/lib
/usr/share/neo4j/system/lib/logback-access-1.1.2.jar
.....
/usr/share/neo4j/system/lib/mimepull-1.6.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/system/README.txt
/usr/share/neo4j/lib
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-shell-2.1.3.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-jmx-2.1.3.jar
....
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.0-2.0.3.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/README.txt
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-graph-matching-2.1.3.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/opencsv-2.0.jar
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/neo4j
/usr/share/doc/neo4j/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/neo4j/copyright
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/neo4j
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/neo4j-shell.1.gz
/var/lib/neo4j/data/log
/var/lib/neo4j/plugins
/var/lib/neo4j/system
/var/lib/neo4j/lib
/var/lib/neo4j/conf
/usr/bin/neo4j-shell
```

Comment: You're guessing he's used a packaged version because he says Ubuntu?  What is the latest packaged version?   I for one would love to use .debs for neo4j, but as far as I can tell they don't keep pace with the releases, so I tend not to.

Comment: The debian installers are part of the build process, so unless they fail due to some reason they should be available with the release.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean on disk, check here (for inspection purposes only of course): `<neo4j_home>/data/graph.db`.

Comment: For some reason I dont have /data/?

Comment: For some reason SO stripped out my angle brackets. That's not supposed to be on the root but relative to the neo4j_home dir. As you can see above data/graph.db most definitely should exist.